# How can I fix my vulkan, why does my vulkaninfo fail?

Tags: ppa, amdgpu, vulkan

If I run `vulkaninfo` I get a seg fault (though I can't find the core dump):

```
$ vulkaninfo 
WARNING: [Loader Message] Code 0 : loader_scanned_icd_add: Driver /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvulkan_nouveau.so supports Vulkan 1.3, but only supports loader interface version 4. Interface version 5 or newer required to support this version of Vulkan (Policy #LDP_DRIVER_7)
WARNING: [Loader Message] Code 0 : terminator_CreateInstance: Failed to CreateInstance in ICD 4.  Skipping ICD.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

However, I can run it like this:

```
$ VK_ICD_FILENAMES=/usr/share/vulkan/icd.d/radeon_icd.x86_64.json:/usr/share/vulkan/icd.d/radeon_icd.i686.json vulkaninfo
```

and it gives expected output, eg if I send it through `| grep driver`:

```
MESA: error: Use of VkSurfacePresentModeCompatibilityEXT without a VkSurfacePresentModeEXT set. This is an application bug.
        driverVersion     = 23.3.1 (96481281)
        driverID        = DRIVER_ID_MESA_RADV
        driverName      = radv
        driverInfo      = Mesa 23.3~git2309020600.1ae3c4~oibaf~l (git-1ae3c40 2023-09-02 lunar-oibaf-ppa)
        driverUUID      = 414d442d-4d45-5341-2d44-525600000000
        driverUUID                        = 414d442d-4d45-5341-2d44-525600000000
        driverID                                             = DRIVER_ID_MESA_RADV
        driverName                                           = radv
        driverInfo                                           = Mesa 23.3~git2309020600.1ae3c4~oibaf~l (git-1ae3c40 2023-09-02 lunar-oibaf-ppa)
        VK_KHR_driver_properties                      : extension revision 1
```

My graphics use AMDGPU driver:

```
$ inxi -G
Graphics:
  Device-1: AMD Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X/590]
    driver: amdgpu v: kernel
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.7 with: Xwayland v: 22.1.8 driver: X:
    loaded: amdgpu unloaded: modesetting dri: radeonsi gpu: amdgpu
    resolution: 1920x1080~75Hz
  API: OpenGL v: 4.6 Mesa 23.3~git2309020600.1ae3c4~oibaf~l (git-1ae3c40
    2023-09-02 lunar-oibaf-ppa) renderer: AMD Radeon RX 580 Series (polaris10
    LLVM 15.0.7 DRM 3.49 6.2.0-31-generic)
```

Is the problem that the oibaf drivers (bleeding edge) are including files I don't want, or is something else going on? This all relates to debugging Steam, most of of my games have stopped launching (CS:GO in particular, not yet updated to CS:GO 2).

```
$ dpkg -S libvulkan_nouveau.so
$ dpkg -L mesa-vulkan-drivers
```

Show that all of the `/usr/share/vulkan/icd.d/*_icd.x86_64.json` and `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvulkan_*.so` files comes from `mesa-vulkan-drivers`.

Example game launch for Dyson Sphere Program:

```
/bin/sh\0-c\0/home/pbhj/.steam/debian-installation/ubuntu12_32/reaper SteamLaunch AppId=1366540 -- /home/pbhj/.steam/debian-installation/ubuntu12_32/steam-launch-wrapper -- '/media/WDblue2TBmedia/games/steamapps/common/SteamLinuxRuntime_sniper'/_v2-entry-point --verb=waitforexitandrun -- '/home/pbhj/.steam/debian-installation/steamapps/common/Proton - Experimental'/proton waitforexitandrun  '/media/WDblue2TBmedia/games/steamapps/common/Dyson Sphere Program/DSPGAME.exe'\0
chdir "/media/WDblue2TBmedia/games/steamapps/common/Dyson Sphere Program"
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/pbhj/.steam/debian-installation/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/pbhj/.steam/debian-installation/ubuntu12_64/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/pbhj/.steam/debian-installation/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/pbhj/.steam/debian-installation/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/pbhj/.steam/debian-installation/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.

(process:8427): steam-runtime-tools-CRITICAL **: 00:06:02.354: _srt_constructor: assertion '_srt_check_not_setuid ()' failed
pressure-vessel-wrap[8427]: E: Cannot run /usr/bin/bwrap: wait status 256
pressure-vessel-wrap[8427]: E: Diagnostic output:
bwrap: setting up uid map: Permission denied

pressure-vessel-wrap[8427]: E: Cannot run /media/WDblue2TBmedia/games/steamapps/common/SteamLinuxRuntime_sniper/pressure-vessel/bin/pv-bwrap: wait status 256
pressure-vessel-wrap[8427]: E: Diagnostic output:
bwrap: setting up uid map: Permission denied

Uploaded AppInterfaceStats to Steam
```